# Python Tkinter threading not working as expected on windows 10

Tags: python, tkinter, python-multithreading

I wrote a Tkinter program that works great except that the entire program freezes when pressing a button that calls a long running function. The user has to wait for the function to finish before doing anything else.
I found a video that showed a solution for this and it worked for the guy in the video but not for me.
The following test case shows the problem.

```
import  tkinter as tk
from random import randint
import time
import threading

root = tk.Tk()

root.title("Test Tkinter Threading")
root.geometry("500x400")

def five_seconds():
    time.sleep(5)
    my_label.config(text="5 Seconds is up!")

def rando():
    random_label.config(text=f'Random Number: {randint(1, 100)}')

my_label = tk.Label(root, text="Hello there!")
my_label.pack(pady=20)

# This works but hangs program while executing five_seconds()
#sleep_button = tk.Button(root, text="5 seconds", command=five_seconds)
#sleep_button.pack(pady=20)

# Supposed to let user keep chosing random numbers while five_seconds() is running.
sleep_button = tk.Button(root, text="5 seconds", 
                         command=threading.Thread(target=five_seconds).start())
sleep_button.pack(pady=20)

random_button = tk.Button(root, text="Pick Random Number", command=rando)
random_button.pack(pady=20)

random_label = tk.Label(root, text="")
random_label.pack(pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

The guy in the video was able to ckick on the sleep button and keep clicking on the random button as expected. When I run this on windows 10 I get a strange result. If I click on the random button the five_seconds() function executes (even though I never hit the sleep buttton). The random button works and does not seem to hange but the program execution is messed up.

Is there an issue with windows 10 and threading Tkinter?

Comment: `command=threading.Thread(target=five_seconds).start()` should be `command=lambda: threading.Thread(target=five_seconds).start()`, or perhaps `command=threading.Thread(target=five_seconds).start` You're calling `start` right away instead of when the button is pressed.

Comment: can you please post a link to the video you are talking about?

Comment: You may want to look into using a `ThreadPool` though. Creating/destroying a thread every time a button is pressed isn't ideal. Submitting jobs to a pool on button press would be a lot cleaner if you can help it.

Comment: Here;s the link to the video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jnrCpA1xJPQ

Comment: command=lambda: threading.Thread(target=five_seconds).start() worked!  I'm not sure why it without lambda for the guy in the video, His command looked like mine including  the ().

Comment: @DaveMathews I watched the video, and his code is broken. Notice how ["5 seconds is up" shows up 5 seconds after he opens the window, not 5 seconds after the button is pressed](https://youtu.be/jnrCpA1xJPQ?t=448). That's sloppy testing on his part.

Comment: BTW: Your other suggestion works as well (removing the ()). command=threading.Thread(target=five_seconds).start). It makes perfect sense now that I think about it.

Comment: Good to hear you got it working. If I were you though, I'd still consider using `from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool` (despite the module, it is mult**threading**). It shares the docs of `multiprocessing.pool.Pool` since they work the same (except using threads instead of processes). Using a pool of threads makes cleanup and the continual submission of jobs easier and more efficient.